# How can I combine DISTINCT and COUNT(*) statements in a single query?

Tags: sql, hive

How can I remove duplicates and find row count in a single query in Hive?

Comment: You should provide some data to work out with

Comment: Aggregated result doesn't have duplicates because different groups have different tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php

Example

```
SELECT column_1, COUNT(DISTINCT(column_2)) FROM table_name GROUP BY column_1
```

Answer (score -1):

I never use Hive before, so I not sure the SQL query is same or not. But you can use this one as reference. I suggest you put the column name with the column has duplicate values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(<column name>) FROM <table>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have never used Hive before, one more way to use is

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT column name) FROM table
```